# Why doesn't the query return any result when the table is populated with the data?

Tags: java, hibernate

The following method tries to get the data for the row that has `java.sql.Time < currentTime`. In spite of table having a `time` entry `less than current time`, the query doesn't return any result and the program never enters the inner while loop.

Why is that ? Where am I going wrong ?

```
private void find() {
    Session session = new HVR().getSession();
    while(isThreadRunning) {

        String hql = "from Scheduled where stime <'" + new java.sql.Time(new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()) + "'";

        List list = session.createQuery(hql).list();
        Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
        System.out.println("Inside outer while loop");

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Inside inner while loop");
            Scheduled scheduled = (Scheduled)iterator.next();
            String tweet = scheduled.getTweet();
            int id = scheduled.getId();
            tweetThread(tweet, id); // Tweet on a separate thread
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try createSQLQuery it works. In HQL , your timestamp is not known

Comment: @Sireesh Why do you need a Timestamp ? Table's column has the datatype `Time`

Comment: Can you enable logging and find out what is the actual query that is getting executed? If possible, run that query in the db and see if it's working. May be the constructed query has issues.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't use `stime < current_time()`?

Comment: @mabi that is what I want to do

Comment: No, I mean literally. [The manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-expressions) explicitly lists `current_time()` as an available HQL expression. No need to construct it in your code (if you really, really want to, I suggest params and `createQuery(hql).setObject(...)`).

Comment: @mabi no particular reason. I didn't know though !

Comment: @mabi I believe it is the same thing ?

Answer (score 0):

The method `toString()` in `java.sql.Time` will get you only the time of the day (something like "12:05:59") without years, months and days. Try using a SimpleDateFormat:

```
//...

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String hql = "from Scheduled where stime <'" +
    dateFormat.format(new java.sql.Time(
        new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis())) + "'";

//...
```

Comment: I never used `java.sql.Date` but `Time`

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit asleep (4:05 am here) answer edited

Comment: Why would I need years months and days ? I am checking for java.sql.time

Comment: The data type of column in the table is `TIME`

Comment: In the database's table `stime` is stored as `HH:mm:ss` and now I would even get years, months and days !

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried but you should be able to express this in HQL naturally using the HQL expression [current_time()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-expressions):

```
String hql = "from Scheduled where stime < current_time()";
List list = session.createQuery(hql).list();
```

If you want to modify the time object (date arithmetic is tricky beyond the above):

```
String hql = "from Scheduled where stime < :prevHour";
List list = session.createQuery(hql)
        .setTime("prevHour", new Date(new Date().getTime() - 3600 * 1000))
        .list();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your hql should use parameter binding, so instead of

```
String hql = "from Scheduled where stime <'" + new java.sql.Time(new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()) + "'";
```

Use something along the lines of:

```
String hql = "from Scheduled where stime < :nowDate";
List list = session.createQuery(hql)
               .setDate("nowDate",new Date())
               .list();
```

If you looking strictly on time you would bind .setTimestamp() instead.

Comment: How will that help in this case ?

Comment: @saplingPro hibernate should be able to generate a valid query when using parameter binding. This is sometimes a better option instead of generating your own hql. In my experience custom queries like the one in the question (especially with date/time) are more prone to errors.